# How to configure Azure Function proxies when using c# class library and deployment form vsts?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Proxies just appear as read-only in azure portal when using deployment automation from VSTS. Is it possible to add proxy definitions to the c# class library (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library) then or what is the recommended workflow for this scenario? Separate function app for the proxies?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put your proxies configurations into `proxies.json` file next to your `host.json` file and deploy it from CI pipeline.

> The proxies that you configure are stored in a `proxies.json` file, which is located in the root of a function app directory. You can manually edit this file and deploy it as part of your app when you use any of the deployment methods that Functions supports.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies#advanced-configuration)